# Show Distinct Result Column of Substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract the prefix (e.g. 12- of 12-111111) of some file names into a column. Then found that there are many duplicated rows in the column. How to show the distinct values in the column?
I tried Group By, but it does not work.
Thank you.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    b.filename, 
    SUBSTRING( b.filename, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1, LEN( filename ) ) AS [prefix] 
FROM
    dbo.share AS b
```

Tried to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    b.filename, 
    SUBSTRING( b.filename, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1 ) AS [prefix] 
FROM
    dbo.share AS b
GROUP BY
    [prefix]
```

```
SELECT 
    b.filename, 
    SUBSTRING( b.filename, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1 ) AS [prefix] 
FROM
    dbo.share AS b
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING( b.filename, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1 )
```

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT TOP 100` without an `ORDER BY`? What kind of results are you getting for that?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please tag your rdbms.

Comment: Expected output is to have a column of distinct prefix (e.g. 12-; 13-; 14-).
Now we have a column of prefix without distinct ( e.g. 12-; 13-; 13-; 14-) because in the filename column it is 12-111111; 13-222222; 13-111111; 14-222222

Comment: Without an ORDER BY, because it has many rows in total. For now we want to save time for it to load.

Comment: Since you want 14- in the same row as 13-111111 it seems you want 2 different result sets to be displayed next to each other.  That would be something for the presentation layer, not really something you do in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
WITH CTE AS(

SELECT 
    b.filename, 
    SUBSTRING( b.filename, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1 ) AS [prefix],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING( b.filename, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', filename ) + 1 )
       ORDER BY b.filename DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM
    dbo.share AS b

)
SELECT filename, prefix
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```